# How to setup JBox2D?

Tags: java, android, box2d

I recently downloaded the JBox2D but how do I set this up?

It's *jbox2d-2.1.2.2*. All I can see is a bunch of code and folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using Maven or Ant; extract the jbox2d-2.1.2.2.zip file and then open up the jbox2d-2.1.2.2\jbox2d-testbed\target directory. Find the below file and then add it to you class path.

```
jbox2d-testbed-2.1.2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

If you are using Maven see the [Getting Started Quide](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/wiki/QuickStart#Jar_Releases)